# Debugger is not evaluating variables

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have old VB.Net project written in framework 3.5. Now I have upgraded framework to 4.6.1. In VS 2017 with 4.6.1 framework debugger is not evaluating variables.

I have tried Clean/Build.
And also tried all solutions from SO to configure debugging options from Tools menu.

Normally when I got this issue Clean/Build would be the solution. But in only this project I am unable to debug.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there something like Debug/Release mode builds in VB.NET, too (like in C#)?

Comment: Yes, and it's set to debug.

Comment: It could be set to debug and still have the "Optimize Code" check box turned on. In my C# projects, "Optimize code" makes debugging hard.

Comment: Yes, It works. If you can make an Answer I will mark it as Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(As of request, here is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123975/debugger-is-not-evaluation-variables?noredirect=1#comment85253183_49123975) as an answer)*

While there is a Debug and a Release build mode, it is still possible that the "Optimize code" check box is activated in a Debug build.

This would make it hard to actually step through your code, inspect variables, and so on.

**Solution:**

Remove the check from the "Optimize code" check box.

[image]

Comment: And for VB.Net Build tab is missing in project properties. Here one can find Optimize Code as "Enable Optimization" under  Compile tab > Advanced Compile Options > Enable Options.